# Simulations in R using for loop

Tags: r

I need help in generating simulations e.g 400 using a for loop for this distribution [image: product from {i=1} to 20 (7/8 + U_i) where U_i ~ Uniform[0,1]]

Comment: Please include your attempt in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the 20 uniform numbers at once, add 7/8 to each of them, and multiply them together. Repeat 400 times.

```
dat=numeric()
for (i in 1:400) {
  dat[i]=prod(runif(20)+7/8)
}
tail(dat)

472.62037 556.99469  83.82873 387.70093 174.87740 210.23188
```

Comment: or `replicate(400, prod(runif(20, 7/8, 1+7/8)))`